# ¿Se puede auto importar el propio componente dentro de la plantilla?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, sourcetree

Estoy necesitando armar en Angular.io una especie de árbol específicamente un Organigrama donde se definen las diferentes áreas, para eso mi duda es si se puede definir un componente que se auto llame dentro de si mismo para que dibuje de manera iterativa el árbol algo asi como lo siguiente:

nodo.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'nodo'
    templateUrl: 'nodo.html'
})
export class NodoComponent {
    @Input() nombre: string;
    @Input() hijos: any[];
}
```

nodo.html

```
<div>
    <label>{{ nombre }}</label>   
    <!-- esta parte nose si se puede hacer -->
    <nodo 
        *ngFor="let nodo of hijos"
        [nombre]="nodo.nombre" 
        [hijos]="nodo.hijos">
    </nodo>
</div>
```

Es posible este tipo de comportamiento en Angular2 o como hay que proceder en estos casos para poder dibujar el árbol, por cierto estuve viendo los componentes disponibles y ninguno me parece suficiente para mi problema en partícula aunque en esta pregunta solo esta reducido a esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible hacer lo que comentas, aunque con algún pequeño cambio.

[**`DEMO STACKBLITZ`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zckgbx)

Supongo que la estructura que tienes que recorrer es algo así:

```
  [
    {
      nombre : 'Wisconsin',
      hijos : [
        { 
          nombre : 'Meteora', 
          hijos : [{ 
            nombre : 'Arkansas',
            hijos : [
              {nombre : 'Jose', hijos : [{
                nombre : 'Hermosilla',
                hijos : [{
                  nombre : 'Rodrigo'
                }]
              }]}
            ]
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Tu componente `Nodo` debe recorrer esa lista y crear nuevos `Nodos` si existe la propiedad `hijos` en un elemento de la lista.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'node',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let element of elements">
      <p>{{element.nombre}}</p>
      <node 
        *ngIf="element.hijos && element.hijos.length"
        [elements]="element.hijos"
      ></node>
    </div>
  `
})
export class NodeComponent  {
  @Input() elements : any[];
}
```

Comment: Si antes de ponerme a escribir código quería saber si era viable o pensarlo de otra manera, anda perfecto tu ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias! Me alegro que te sirviera. Te recomiendo esa página (StackBlitz) para hacer pequeñas pruebas y así no tener que escribir código en tu proyecto que no estés del todo seguro. Puedes crear proyectos Angular, Ionic y React. Saludos =)

Comment: +1 no solo por la respuesta.. no conocía: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)... muy bueno